# What are good client libraries for streaming HLS on the web?

Tags: client, http-live-streaming

HLS Streaming is becoming more popular.  I am researching what clients are possible on the web.  Not iOS or android... Web browsers.

So far the candidates are:

- JW Player: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19578/what-is-video-streaming  so far, it has only worked on OS X/Safari, which is consistent w/ the table near the bottom of the page.
- thePlatform:  The PDK work with OS X/Safari.

As far as I can tell, OS X/Safari supports HLS streaming in the <video> tag, which makes it really easy.

What is the best method to support HLS on the most browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC has some support for HLS. It's being sponsored by Anevia.
[http://demo.anevia.com:8080/ott/vlc.php]

VLC has plugins for browsers on several platforms. I don't know if the VLC solution is ready for prime time yet, but it does exist.

Answer (score 2):

jwplayer have support for HLS in one of their dev branches, I tested & it's quite good, apart from the issues mentioned in the thread:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/15223/flash-http-streaming-support

Answer (score 1):

[Mediaelement](http://mediaelementjs.com/) with [HLS support](https://github.com/mangui/flashls) is MIT licence and works great on both iDevices and Desktop Browsers, with fallback for HLS. No need to pay for plugins when you have this great open-source alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers HLS is supported natively through the HTML video tag. For support [see that list here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/hls/).

At the time of writing Safari, iOS and Android seem to be the only ones supported that.

Answer (score -5):

Any browser that fully supports HTML5 markup should display the HLS with the video <> tag.

Comment: Tested.  So far, only apple safari is supporting.

Comment: wrong information. HLS supported client is listed in here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming#Clients

Comment: It is a very wrong information. HLS video is very device specific. For example, Opera on desktop doesn't support it, but Opera on Amino STB supports.